# Difference between "progress hopefully" and "hopefully progress"

Tags: meaning

I understand from context that both are different, but what rule applies here? Is there a general case where you change the word order and you change the meaning?

Comment: You may get better suited help if you provide more context to those fragments. How do you plan to use them? Where did you encounter them?

Comment: Please, include the context!!

Answer (score 1):

The statement

> I will hopefully progress through high school

means that I hope (now) that I will progress through high school. On the other hand the statement

> I will progress hopefully through high school

means that as I progress through high school I will be hopeful, most likely of achieving a high score that will give me entry into the university course I want.

Answer (score 0):

We have to clarify one thing here.

> **progress hopefully**

is more like an imperative to me, though it does sound extraordinarily quaint. *Progress hopefully* is an awkward attempt to say something like *I hope you'll make progress.* but it's not a sentence I would want to use. I would simply say *Make the best of it!* and that's it.

> **hopefully progress**

can be applied in a sentence where there's a split infinitive. Once again, it still has a strange sound.